# Mercurial repository log including subrepositories

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-subrepos, changelist

In our build scripts I use the templated `hg log` command to get a changelist for a particular build. This works great, but unfortunately it does not include changes in the subrepos (we have more than 10 of them). I would like to include them too, but there seems to be no such command.

I'm thinking about writing a script that:

1. Enumerates the .hgsubstate file at the starting revision
2. Finds out the subrepos and their starting revisions
3. Runs `hg log` for them
4. Merges and sorts the results by date.

Is there any other simpler way? Maybe a command I'm missing?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5757511/800151), which addresses the issue, if not a duplicate.  Also, note that merged log is [on the Hg Todo list](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/SubrepoWork#log).

Answer (score 0):

Since it's apparently on the todo for a <strike>while</strike> **years** and otherwise unavailable, I wrote my own `subtools.py`:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import hglib
import os
import sys

def get_substate(client, rev=None):
    substate_filename = os.path.join(client.root(), '.hgsubstate')
    if os.path.isfile(substate_filename):
        lines = client.cat([substate_filename], rev).split('\n')
        return { key : value for (value,key) in [ line.split() for line in lines if line ]}
    else:
        return {}


def substate_diff(client, revA, revB):
    substate_a = get_substate(client, revA)
    substate_b = get_substate(client, revB)
    key_union = set(substate_b) | set(substate_a)

    diff = {}
    for key in key_union:
       diff[key] = (substate_a[key], substate_b[key])

    return diff

def recursive_log(path, revA, revB):
    logtree = { 'logs': [], 'subrepos': {}}

    try:
        client = hglib.open(path)
    except:
        return logtree

    if revA == revB:
        print("no changes on {}".format(client.root()))
        return logtree

    print("Checking {} between {} and {}...".format(client.root(), revA, revB))

    for key, revisions in substate_diff(client, revA, revB).iteritems():
        if revisions[0] and revisions[1]:
            logtree['subrepos'][key] = recursive_log(os.path.join(client.root(),key), revisions[0], revisions[1])
        elif revisions[0] and not revisions[1]:
            print("removed subrepo with path: %s"%key, file=sys.stderr)
        elif revisions[1] and not revisions[2]:
            print("added subrepo with path: %s"%key, file=sys.stderr)

    logtree['logs'] = client.log("%s:%s"%(revA,revB))
    return logtree
```

use as such:

```
In [15]: log = subtools.recursive_log('./', '947', '951')
```